# Getting Link-Local IP after Initial Switch Configuration

Tags: cisco, switch, dhcp

I have two 2960X switches and a 3750X switch. I am trying to configure these switches so that the 3750X switch acts as a core switch and connects to the two 2960X switches. Each of the 2960X switches will then connect to several SG-200 switches, which clients will be connected to, with the exception of one SG-200 switch, which will connect to several servers. The infrastructure does not use any routers and is not connected to the Internet or any other network.

I was able to successfully access and run the browser-based express setup on the 3750X and 2960X switches. After configuring the switches, I was able to access them at the new IP addresses I set for them. However, after I finished configuring the 2960X switch and went to change some settings on the 3750X, I have been unable to configure any of the switches. When I enter the IPs of each switch in my browser, I only get warnings that I cannot access the page from the browser. I have noticed that previously, when connected to the switches, the IP address on the client that I am using to configure the switches was in the same 10.0.1.X subnet. However, now the client’s IP address when connected to any of the switches is a link-local address - 169.254.X.X..

How can I configure the clients to get an address within the subnet? In the future, I will be using a DHCP server, but for now I am only trying to get basic configuration done and have not yet setup a DHCP server. Is a separate DHCP server my only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to statically assign an IP address to your client or setup a DHCP server.  If the client is setup as a DHCP client and there is no server available, it will auto-assign itself a 169.254.x.x addrsss.